# Counter error when changing input field value

Tags: javascript, counter, addeventlistener

There is a field for entering numbers and buttons for incrementing and decrementing its value. They work with a **default value**, but if the user enters any number forcibly, the value is **not updated** after pressing the buttons. Tell me, what could be the problem, what to look for?

```
<div class="element">
    <button class="decrement" id="decrement" onclick="number_counter(this)">-</button>
    <input type="number" name="" id="parameter" value="10">
    <button class="increment" id="increment" onclick="number_counter(this)">+</button>
</div>
<script>
    const coefficient_input = document.getElementById('parameter');

    coefficient_input.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
        current_value = event.target.value;
        coefficient_input.setAttribute('value', current_value);
        console.log(current_value);
    });

    function number_counter(button) {
        let id = button.getAttribute('id');
        let step = 0.01;

        coefficient_input.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
            current_value = event.target.value;
            coefficient_input.setAttribute('value', current_value);
            console.log(current_value);
        });

        switch(id) {
            case 'increment':
                let increment = (parseFloat(coefficient_input.getAttribute('value')) + step).toFixed(2) ;
                coefficient_input.setAttribute('value', increment);
                break;
            case 'decrement':
                let decrement = (parseFloat(coefficient_input.getAttribute('value')) - step).toFixed(2);
                coefficient_input.setAttribute('value', decrement);
                break;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to work with an event listener, but after changing the input field without pressing the buttons, the value changes.

Comment: Don't use `.setAttribute()` to set the value of an input. Assign to its `.value` property.

Comment: The `value` attribute is the initial default value, not the current value.